# Вызывается исключение при удаление элементов из очереди

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Мне нужно реализовать очереди без библиотек. При вызове в первый раз все работает, но если после вызвать еще раз то вызывается исключение которое указывает на функцию Pop(). Но я не понимаю что в ней не так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>

int menu();

struct Node
{
    int value;
    Node* next = nullptr;
};

struct Queue
{
    Node* first = nullptr;
    Node* last = nullptr;
    
    void Push(int number)
    {
        Node* tmp = new Node();
        if (last == nullptr)
        {
            first = tmp;
            last = tmp;
        }
        tmp->value = number;
        last->next = tmp;
        last = tmp;
        last->next = nullptr;
    }

    void Pop()
    {
        Node* tmp = first;
        while (tmp != nullptr && tmp->next != nullptr)
        {
            first = tmp;
            tmp = first->next;
            delete (first);
        }
        delete (tmp);
    }

    void printQueue()
    {
        Node* tmp = first;
        while (tmp->next != nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << tmp->value << " ";
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        std::cout << tmp->value << std::endl;
    }

};

int menu()
{
    Queue queue = Queue();
    char c;
    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "\nStack and Queue\n"
            << "1. Zapolnit' queue vozrastaushimi chislami\n"
            << "2. Zapolnit' queue ybivaushimii chislami\n"
            << "3. Zapolnit' queue random chislami\n"
            << "0. Exit\n\n";
        c = _getch();
        switch (c)
        {
        case '1':
            std::cout << "Queue\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                queue.Push(i);
            }
            queue.printQueue();

            for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--)
            {
                queue.Pop();
            }

            break;
        case '2':
            std::cout << "Queue\n";
            for (int i = 100; i > 90; i--)
            {
                queue.Push(i);
            }
            queue.printQueue();
            for (int i = 100; i > 90; i--)
            {
                queue.Pop();
            }
            break;

        case '3':
            std::cout << "Queue\n";
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                queue.Push(rand() % 100);
            }
            queue.printQueue();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                queue.Pop();
            }

            break;

        case '0':
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    menu();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: не забудьте нас отблагодарить жмякнувши стрелочку вверх и по возможности галочку

Answer (score 1):

```
first = tmp;
```

здесь копируются указатели.

Потом удаляем

```
delete (first);
```

а потом удаляется ещё раз (а вот это уже проблема)

```
delete (tmp);
```

При копировании указателей копируются только указатели, но не объекты. И если удалить объект по одному указателю, то по второму удалять его уже не нужно. Он уже удален. Но вот только указатель об этом не знает, если только не "умный указатель"

Answer (score 0):

Что-то не ладное тут с освобождением памяти `delete`!
План действий:

- Мне кажется, что метод `pop()` - удаляет все элементы! Поэтому вызывайте его только раз!
- Внесите `Queue queue = Queue();` в цикл

И все непременно заработает!